# Memory usage shown with `free` command does not match the utilization from System Monitor

Tags: linux, memory

When I am using `free -m` to check memory status, I get the following:

```
$ free -m
         total     used     free    shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      7641     5125      188       739        2327        1476
Swap:     3755        0     3755
```

This shows 67.07% in used memory and 30.05% in buffered/cache.

However when I look at the System Monitor (I am using Ubuntu 18.04), I see this:

```
Memory
5.9 GB (78.8%) of 7.5 GB
```

These two do not match up. Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `free`: 5128+739=5864, which is close enough to your 5.9 GB.  Where's the issue?

**¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: Thanks. it seems I had ignored the shared memory usage. They add up, just that I failed to notice. I actually spent some time trying to make sense of it. But I overlooked something shown right there.